# Use multiple setting files and select them at run time

Tags: c#, application-settings

As of today, I have an `App.config` file in my project.

I use my config settings in the program like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileDir"];
```

Where *FileDir* is a setting in `App.config` defined like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="FileDir" value="C:\MyFolder" />
</appSettings>
```

In my build folder (be it `Debug` or `Release`) the file will show up as `MyProject.exe.config` if my project is named `MyProject`.

I'd like to add multiple similar config files with the exact same variables but different values and I'd like to point to the config file using command line arguments so that I can reuse the same program but with different settings.

How can I tell my program which config file to choose?

Comment: Why don't you just create many keys and use a prefix as id?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno that can also work. But I don't think that's optimal, is it? Also my customer does not want to change any settings in the old version of the program. I'd go with that if I find no better alternative.

Comment: Answered with my solution

Comment: You can use [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path_to_file)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) - _"Opens the specified client configuration file as a Configuration object."_

Comment: @stuartd I will try it out and come back to you. Thanks.

Comment: @stuartd could you post an example code on how to use the new settings after loading with `OpenExeConfiguration`?

Comment: @Disasterkid something like - `var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);  string fileDir = config.AppSettings.Settings["FileDir"].Value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="WordV1" value="abc" />
    <add key="WordV2" value="def" />
    <add key="WordV3" value="ghi" />
</appSettings>
```

---

```
string word = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WordV" + user.version];
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal approach would be to have transform files which are applied based on the build config.  So you still only have one config file but it gets built differently depending on the intended use of the build.

something like SlowCheetah does this, or if you're using something like octopus deploy for deployments then that could do it at deployment time.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms

Comment: The OP is asking for a *runtime* selection process but your answer is for a *build-time* selection process.

Answer (score 0):

How about a different solution, especially after stating:

> As of today, I have an App.config file in my project.

Why do you not have your own settings class? You could maintain it with a default set of settings in code - something that is much cleaner than trying to maintain several App.config files. Something like:

```
[Serializable]
public class AppSettings
{
  public string FileDir { get; set; }

  public AppSettings()
  {
    FileDir = string.Empty;
  }

  public AppSettings(string fDir)
  {
    FileDir = fDir;
  }

  public void SetDefault()
  {
    FileDir = "SomeDefault";
  }
}
```

You could have different instances, or depending on what you need to do, you could load the second set of settings:

```
m_dSettings = SettingsIO.GetSettings(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "DefaultSettings.xml"));
m_cSettings = SettingsIO.GetSettings(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "CustomSettings.xml"));
m_eSettings = new AppSettings("F:\\Dir");

SettingsIO.WriteSettings(m_dSettings, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "DefaultSettings.xml"));
SettingsIO.WriteSettings(m_dSettings, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "CustomSettings.xml"));
SettingsIO.WriteSettings(m_eSettings, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "ExtraSettings.xml"));
```

The class to persist the above:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

public static class SettingsIO
{
  public static void WriteSettings(AppSettings settings, string settingsFilePath)
  {
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppSettings));

    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(settingsFilePath)))
      Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(settingsFilePath));

    using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(settingsFilePath))
      serializer.Serialize(SW, settings);
  }

  public static AppSettings GetSettings(string settingsFilePath)
  {
    AppSettings m_Settings = null;

    if (File.Exists(settingsFilePath))
    {
      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppSettings));

      using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(settingsFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS))
          m_Settings = (AppSettings)serializer.Deserialize(SR);
    }

    if (m_Settings == null)
      m_Settings = new AppSettings();

    return m_Settings;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks solid. Let me try it out and come back.